# Dynamically creating the entity and attributes of a core data model using json (attributes)

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

I want to create the core data entity and its attributes by using json attributes (arrays, dictionaries) dynamically.
Can anyone provide me the code for that?
I found some links here but that are not working.